# Checkstyle not working

Tags: maven-2, checkstyle

I am new to maven and chekstyle, so need to ask some question... I want to use checkstyle in my maven based project, so in my `pom.xml` I have add the dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>checkstyle</groupId>
   <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and also I have added the entry in plugin tag:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <enableRulesSummary>true</enableRulesSummary>
    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But when I run my maven build with command `mvn clean install`, checkstyle doesn't do anything. And as I dont have any `checkstyle.xml` in my system yet, shouldn't it complains me about the error?

What else configuration am I missing?

Comment: you can also take a look at [qulice-maven-plugin](http://www.qulice.com/qulice-maven-plugin/index.html) that combines together Checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs and a few other static analyzers, and pre-configures them

Answer (score 8):

> I want to use checkstyle in my maven based project, so in my pom.xml  I've add the dependency (...)

You don't need to add this dependency, you just need to declare the plugin (a plugin declares its own dependencies).

> (...) But when I run my maven build with command mvn clean install, checkstyle doesn't do anything.

Yes because you only **declared** the plugin, you did not bind the [`check`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html) goal to a lifecycle phase, so a normal build doesn't trigger the checkstyle plugin. If you want `checkstyle:check` to be triggered as part of your build, you need to declare the `check` goal inside an execution (it binds itself by default to the `verify` phase). Something like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <!-- Lock down plugin version for build reproducibility -->
  <version>2.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
    ...
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now, calling any phase including `verify` will invoke checkstyle.

> And as I don't have any checkstyle.xml in my system yet, shouldn't it complains me about the error?

It will... when called (either explicitly by `mvn checkstyle:check` or as part of the build if you modify your setup as suggested).